# Mirroring keyboard to multiple computers

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to use my keyboard at the same time for multiple PCs. Here what I mean is not a KVM switch that extends the monitor or switches the input device, such as Synergy or Barrier, but mirroring the keyboard inputs. For example when I pressed ctrl-→ (arrow right) on the host (server) machine the same key or key combination in this case ctrl-→ should be fired on the client machine(s).

Is there any programmatical solution or software solution for this?

Edit: hardware solution is also nice if it's not very expensive or difficult to implement

Edit: The machines are all Windows, under a same local network. It should work for GUI applications, not CLI automation, in my case specifically on chrome (brave) browser (but note that I don't mean browser automation solution such as selenium or puppeteer, I need a general solution for the OS GUI operation)

Answer (score 0):

The term for what you are asking for is
[Multi-boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-boxing),
used mainly for game cheating:

> Multi-boxing or multiboxing refers to playing as multiple separate characters concurrently in an MMORPG. This can either be achieved by using multiple separate machines to run the game or by running multiple separate instances of the game.

Some of the software developed for gaming might be useful for you.
Below are several that seem to be potentially useful:

- [Keyclone](https://solidice.com/downloads/windows/keyclone) (free)
- [ISBoxer](https://isboxer.com/) (free)
- [Lidc](https://www.lidcmultiboxing.com/)
  ($35/year, 30-day trial - much too costly)